# What is the name of this procedure?

Tags: normalization, standardization

Frequently, normalization means subtracting the mean and dividing by SD.

What if one standardizes the data by subtracting the median and dividing by interquartile range? Does that procedure have a name?

Comment: Subtracting the median and dividing by IQR is no more nonparametric than subtracting the mean and dividing by SD is. It may be less affected by gross outliers (a form of robustness), but that doesn't make it nonparametric.

Comment: Agree; I changed the title accordingly.

Comment: How about "robust normalization"? :-)

Comment: One might say something like "quartile-based standardization", perhaps